# How to ignore unrecognized command line parameters

Tags: c#, .net, system.commandline

I'm testing out System.CommandLine.

There will be several options passed to my executable, but I only care about one of them.  If I don't define them all, I will get errors:

```
Unrecognized command or argument '-i'.
Unrecognized command or argument '3'.
```

Is there any way that I can tell System.CommandLine to ignore any options that aren't specified by my code?  E.g.:

```
var root = New RootCommand("Test application");
var cmd = new Command("--example", "example command");
root.Add(cmd);
await root.InvokeAsync(args);
```

Then if I try calling my program via:

```
test example --startDir=C:\temp --FileCnt=7 --Delay=10
```

I'll get 6 of those 'Unrecognized command or argument' errors.

The reason that I would like to not have to specify all the options is that my program is called from another program.  The parameters are being passed from the calling program, and I don't know what all of them will be.

I do know what the two important ones I need to parse are, and the rest I don't care about.

Comment: Not really clear what the issue is.  Sounds like a simple if-block or switch-block should take care of it.  Just handle the arguments you care about.

Comment: System.CommandLine automatically generates those error messages when it finds options that weren't specified.  I haven't been able to find a flag telling it to not create those error messages.

Comment: Didn't realize `System.CommandLine` was a new package.  See [How to specify C# System.Commandline behaviour when no arguments are provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74111111/719186), it might have some bits that relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I recently run into similar problems. For my workaround, I try to call parse first then invoke. Like this:

```
var processedRes = Commands.RootCommand.Parse(args);
await processedRes.InvokeAsync();
```

This will ignore all unknown tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The command type has a property **TreatUnmatchedTokensAsErrors** that you can set to false.

```
command.TreatUnmatchedTokensAsErrors = false;
```

[more info in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/model-binding#parseresult)